# Decompiling code involving anonymous types and lambda expressions

Tags: c#, .net

A .NET project which I decompiled to make a slight change does not compile any more due to cryptical compiler code. These code parts might be due to lambda expressions and anonymous types involved.

I tried to understand the respective code snippets in order to change them back to working/sccessfully compiling  syntax, without success.

```
public static void DoEvents()
{
  Dispatcher dispatcher = System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher;
  Action action;      
  if (common._Closure\u0024__.\u0024I13\u002D0 != null)
  {        
    action = common._Closure\u0024__.\u0024I13\u002D0;
  }
  else
  {       
    common._Closure\u0024__.\u0024I13\u002D0 = action 
    = (Action)(() => {  });
}
dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, (Delegate)action);
}
```

I wonder whether this "cryptical" outcome from code decompiling is somehow avoidable when using a tool as e.g. dotPeek and if not, how to fix it to make it compilable again.

Comment: Is it a winforms app by any chance ?

Comment: Have you tried using ILSpy as an alternative to dotPeek?

Comment: This in fact is some custom code of the application I decompiled. It is not any WinForms code. The application by the way is a WPF application. @StriplingWarrior: Actually I also tried ILSpy, yes.

Comment: the `_Closure$__.$I13-0` name seems to be randomly generated name during compilation, so seems fine to replace it with whatever name you want

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you're trying to decompile the `public static void DoEvents()` method in System.Windows.Forms.dll.
No need for that you can just browse the .NET framework source code.

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/

Your method is in Application.cs

Comment: [That doesn't look like](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Application.cs,0880978c39425ff1) the code that the OP decompiled

Answer (score 0):

I haven't dealt with code quite like this before, but it looks like the lambda expression itself has been correctly decompiled, and the code that's not been decompiled is some kind of optimization to avoid creating a new Action each time the code is invoked. (Since the given lambda has no captured variables, it can be treated as a singleton.)

So I think the effective starting code would be:

```
public static void DoEvents()
{
  Dispatcher dispatcher = System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher;
  dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, () => {  });
}
```